# React Native pull to refresh section list from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I recently changed from nested flatlist to section list in my app. I want to keep all the functionality from before. After logging in the list must be refreshed, so I was calling the child method from my component triggering the refresh and to make sure my refresh "icon" is in the view I was using scroll to offset. This seems to be impossible using section list.How do you keep your refresh indicators in view when you refresh? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing similar issue the solve is calling this method (from ref):

```
this.mySectionList.scrollToLocation({
    itemIndex : 0,
    sectionIndex : 0 ,
    viewOffset: 70,
    viewPosition: 0 ,
    animated: true
})
```

and then calling the function that is our refresh handler. The tricky part is when the list is empty but still needs to be updated. Then I passed a "fake" section, together with title and data. For this specific section I changed opacity to 0 so that it is invisible but the list can still navigate there. Hope this will help someone!